# Opencv 2.1 Sobel detector passing error

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to perform a Sobel transform on an image however it gives this error:

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'cv::Mat&' from expression of type 'IplImage*'|
>   cv.hpp|254|error: in passing argument 2 of 'void cv::Sobel(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int, int, int, double, double, int)'|
>   ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Is it a case of me misunderstanding what the manual is stating?
I'm using opencv v2.1 documentation

```
 IplImage* img=cvLoadImage("fight1.png");

           CvMat *mat = cvCreateMat(img->height,img->width,CV_32FC3 );
           //Get width and height
           int w=img->width;
           int h=img->height;
           //create Images
           IplImage* img2=cvCreateImage( cvSize( w, h ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
           IplImage* img3=cvCreateImage( cvSize( w, h ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
           //convert to Mat
           cvConvert(img,mat);

           //prepare stream reader
           ofstream ob;
           ob.open("object.txt");

            //Perform Sobel
           cvCvtColor( img,img2,CV_RGB2GRAY);
           Sobel(img2,img3,32 ,1,3,1.0,1.0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
            //cvLaplace( img, img2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix the C and C++ syntax. Choose one of them, and use the documentation for the correct one.

Here you declared matrices in C style (IplImage), and called cv::Sobel(), instead of cvSobel().